# How to extract columns from a textfile in java

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

Here is a screenshot of the textfile I want to read in to my program.

I want to build a GUI to display the attributes of a specific user. So I need to extract the information from this textfile but I don't know how exactly. The perfect outcome would be having each header as the String name and then store the rest of the elements in that column to the that String. Any help would be appreciated.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("charList.txt");
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = "";
while (bf.readLine()!= null){
    line += bf.readLine();
}
String [] temp = new String [];
temp = line.split("\\s");
```

[image]

Comment: Start with a `Map<String, List<String>>`` as a storage mechanism.  Personally, I would simply read each line, break it down into it's individual columns and store that in a `List` of `List`, but that's me

Answer (score 0):

The 'header' lines are a problem, merging them coherently would be a challenging. I would recommend that you simply ignore that and hard code (or in a config file) the the problem:

```
private class CharListField {
    private String fieldname;
    private int offset;
    private int len;
}


CharListField[] fields = {new CharListField("user id", 0, 8),
                          .....,
                          new CharListField("end xp", 40, 6)};

BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = "";
boolean gotheaders = false;
while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
    if (!gotheaders) {
         // skip lines till you get an empty one.
         if (line.trim().length() == 0) {
             gotheaders = true;
         }
         continue;
    }
    for (CharListField field : fields) {
         String value = line.substring(field.offset, field.offset + field.len).trim();
         // do something with the value for the field....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know your file first then you will find the method to read it.

It can be that in your file is used a delimiter that separate the data structures.

But more probably is that, your file is structured by position.

This can mean that the  `user is` can be found between position 0 and 10, `starting xp` can be found between 11 and 20 etc.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered structuring your text file as json?